# Create new dataframe in Pandas that expands hourly data and hourly temperature reading to quarter-hour intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, resampling

Edit: I figured it out:

df_weather_test = df_weather

df_weather_test['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_weather['date_time'])

df_weather_test2 = df_weather_test.resample('15T', on='date_time').mean().interpolate()

---

I have a dataset that has hourly time intervals with each hour containing its own temperature reading. For the purposes of my project, I want to change the time intervals to quarter-hour time intervals and have the temperatures be the estimated in-between readings from base hour 1 to base hour 2.

For example, I have this:

date_time.           Temperature [°C]

2018-01-01 01:00:00         10

2018-01-01 02:00:00.        12

and I would like a new dataframe that looks like this:

date_time.            Temperature [°C]

2018-01-01 01:00:00         10

2018-01-01 01:15:00.        10.5

2018-01-01 01:30:00         11

2018-01-01 01:45:00.        11.5

2018-01-01 02:00:00.        12

How would I go about adding in the extra three rows per hour and then having each be the base temperature plus 25%, 50%, and 75%, respectively of the total hourly temperature change?

I know I can use this to insert a row into the dataframe at a given location:

df_test.loc[1.5] = ['time', 'temp_old', 'temp_new']

df_test = df_test.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

Do I need a loop that starts at row 1 of the original dataframe, takes the temperature difference from row 1 to row 0, divides it by 4 and then adds that value to a new inserted column in the dataframe, that value * 2 to a second inserted column in the dataframe, and that value *3 to a third inserted column in the dataframe?

Does anyone have any idea of what that may look like?

I tried the above (inserting into the dataframe and then manually adding in the values), but I'm not sure how I would use this for the entire 5000+ row dataset.

Comment: you are looking for resample 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Answer (score 0):

```
# create the dataframe
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=9, freq='H')
series = pd.Series([10,12,13,14,14,15,14,13,12], index=index)
df = pd.DataFrame(series, columns=['Temp'])
# shift the Temp column
df['shifted'] = df.Temp.shift(-1)
df.shifted = df.shifted.ffill()
# a function to fill the values in between intervals
def fill_temp(x):
    diff = x.shifted - x.Temp
    if x['index'].minute == 15:
        temp = x.Temp + .25 * diff
    elif x['index'].minute == 30:
        temp = x.Temp + .5 * diff
    elif x['index'].minute == 45:
        temp = x.Temp + .75 * diff
    else:
        temp = x.Temp
    return temp

# do a resample
df_resampled = df.resample('.25H').ffill().reset_index()
# apply the function to modify the values and add them into a new column
df_resampled['Temperature'] = df_resampled.apply(fill_temp, axis=1)

df_resampled = df_resampled[['index','Temperature']].rename(columns={'index':'DateTime'})
print (df_resampled)
```